# How can I create a bash or zsh alias for git commit, git pull, git push and pull on a remote server?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, zshrc, zsh-alias

If I type the following into Terminal I can accomplish everything I want:

```
git commit -am "my commit message" ; git pull ; git push ; ssh user@server 'cd /path/to/git/repo/ ; git pull ; exit'
```

I'd like to create the same as an alias in my `~/.zshrc`. Something like:

```
alias pushit () { git commit -am "$@" ; git pull ; git push ; ssh user@server 'cd /path/to/git/repo/ ; git pull ; exit' }
```

To be run in Terminal like so:

```
pushit "my commit message"
```

Instead every time I reload ~/.zshrc (`source ~/.zshrc`) or open a new Terminal window I see it loop through my alias dozens of times. It's not clear it actually runs.

What am I doing wrong?

**Notes:**

1. This is not for a mission critical server. It's just for personal use. I know it's poor form.
2. I'd rather not use git's [alias] tools so I can keep all of my aliases in the same place (`~/.zshrc`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a function rather than an alias:

```
function pushit () { 
    git commit -am "$@"
    git pull
    git push
    ssh user@server -- 'cd /path/to/git/repo/ ; git pull'
}
```

Comment: When I use this function, my terminal gives me an `fatal: bad revision`-Error. What does that mean?

Comment: For some reasons it ignores the quotation marks. But I can't figure out why